# Service Bus Output binding for Java based Azure Function is not working - No errors

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I try to build Java based Azure Function to be triggered by HTTP and sending data to Topic of Service Bus. This is based on sample code. HTTP Trigger works fine(Hello name is returned), but I don't get any data sent to Service Bus. And I do not get error message. I have tested with C# based Function that that "queueconstring" in local.settings.json is correct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=java

```
/* 20.3.2020 HTTP Trigger and Topic output binding*/
package com.function;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class HttpTriggerSBOutputJava {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpTriggerSBOutputJava". Two ways to invoke it using 
   "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpTriggerSBOutputJava
     * 2. curl {your host}/api/HttpTriggerSBOutputJava?name=HTTP%20Query
     */


    @FunctionName("HttpTriggerSBOutputJava")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        @ServiceBusTopicOutput(name = "message", topicName = "ContactInformationChanged", subscriptionName = "Playground", connection = "queueconstring") OutputBinding<String> message,
        final ExecutionContext context) {

        String name = request.getBody().orElse("Azure Functions");

        message.setValue(name);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();

    }
```

}

Comment: Hi, kenny. Any update on this question? Have you test the code I post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code, it works fine on my side:

**Function.java**

```
package com.function;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
     * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
     */
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    @ServiceBusTopicOutput(name = "message", topicName = "test", subscriptionName = "test", connection = "ServiceBusConnection")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "ServiceBusConnection":"Endpoint=sb://bowmantest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: QueueTrigger won't have any return type, how can we do error handling for that scenario?